# Spiral Matrix: Inner Functions Work But Throw Error When Used In While Loop

Tags: javascript, matrix, typeerror

A Spiral Matrix coding challenge in JavaScript; of particular importance are the four inner functions `leftToRight`, `topToBottom`, `rightToLeft`, and `bottomToTop`. Commenting out the while loop and invoking the four functions within the scope of `spiralCopy` like so:

```
leftToRight(iLeftRightStart, iLeftRightEnd, leftRightPosition);
topToBottom(iTopBottomStart, iTopBottomEnd, topBottomPosition);
rightToLeft(iRightLeftStart, iRightLeftEnd, rightLeftPosition);
bottomToTop(iBottomTopStart, iBottomTopEnd, bottomTopPosition);
```

Returns `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 25, 19, 13, 7 ]`, as expected.

However, when used in the while loop in the code below the program crashes with the following error:

```
spiral.push(matrix[position][i]);
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Here is the entire program:

```
inputMatrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
  [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
  [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
]

const spiralCopy = (matrix) => {
  const spiralLength = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;
  const spiral = [];

  let iLeftRightStart = 0; // +1
  let iLeftRightEnd = matrix[0].length; // -1
  let leftRightPosition = 0; // +1
  let iTopBottomStart = 1; // +1
  let iTopBottomEnd = matrix.length; // -1
  let topBottomPosition = matrix[0].length - 1; // -1
  let iRightLeftStart = matrix[0].length - 2; // -1
  let iRightLeftEnd = 0; // +1
  let rightLeftPosition = matrix.length - 1; // -1
  let iBottomTopStart = matrix.length - 2; // -1
  let iBottomTopEnd = 1; // +1                      
  let bottomTopPosition = 0; // +1

  const leftToRight = (iStart, iEnd, position) => {
    console.log(iStart, iEnd, position);
    for (let i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
      spiral.push(matrix[position][i]);
    }
  }

  const topToBottom = (iStart, iEnd, position) => {
    for (let i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
      spiral.push(matrix[i][position]);
    }
  }

  const rightToLeft = (iStart, iEnd, position) => {
    for (let i = iStart; i >= iEnd; i--) {
      spiral.push(matrix[position][i]);
    }
  }

  const bottomToTop = (iStart, iEnd, position) => {
    for (let i = iStart; i >= iEnd; i--) {
      spiral.push(matrix[i][position]);
    }
  }

  while (spiral.length < spiralLength) {
    leftToRight(iLeftRightStart, iLeftRightEnd, leftRightPosition);
    topToBottom(iTopBottomStart, iTopBottomEnd, topBottomPosition);
    rightToLeft(iRightLeftStart, iRightLeftEnd, rightLeftPosition);
    bottomToTop(iBottomTopStart, iBottomTopEnd, bottomTopPosition);
    iLeftRightStart++;
    iLeftRightEnd--;
    leftRightPosition--;
    iTopBottomStart++;
    iTopBottomEnd--;
    topBottomPosition--;
    iRightLeftStart--;
    iRightLeftEnd++;
    rightLeftPosition--;
    iBottomTopStart--;
    iBottomTopEnd++;
    bottomTopPosition++;
  }
  return spiral;
}
console.log(spiralCopy(inputMatrix));
// should print [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 25, 19, 13, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 17, 23, 29, 28, 27, 26, 20, 14, 15, 16, 22, 21]
```

Why are the functions not working in the while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was decrementing `leftRightPosition` instead of incrementing it.

I changed the

```
leftRightPosition--;
```

To

```
leftRightPosition++;
```

And it works.